# If $S$ is a simple $\mathbb{C}G$-module and $U$ is a one-dimensional $\mathbb{C}G$-module, then $S \otimes U$ is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, modules

> Show that if $S$ is a simple $\mathbb{C}G$-module and $U$ is a one-dimensional 
>   $\mathbb{C}G$-module, then $S \otimes U$ is simple.

I've tried to prove this fact, but I think ther's a mistake because my proof it's too trivial and don't use all hypothesis! 
This is my proof:

If $S \otimes U$ isn't simple, then the representation $\rho_S \otimes \rho_U$ is reducible, namely there is $S_1 \otimes U$, with $S_1 \subset S$, a subspace of $S \otimes U$ fixed by $\rho_S \otimes \rho_U (G) $. Then: $\rho_S \otimes \rho_U (g)(S_1 \otimes U)\subset S_1 \otimes U $ $\Rightarrow$ $ \rho_S(g)S_1 \otimes \rho_U(g)U\subset S_1\ \otimes U $ $\Rightarrow$ $\rho_S(g)S_1 \subset S_1$ and $\rho_U(g)\subset U$ $\Rightarrow$ $S_1$ and $U$ aren't simple.

Comment: Why don't you think you have used all the hypotheses?

Comment: I don't use the fact that U has dimension 1

Comment: If $U$ did not have dimension $1$, why would your claim about a subspace having the form $S_1\otimes U$ be true?

Comment: I mean that if U did not have dimension 1, I could take $S_1 \otimes U_1$ rather than $S_1 \otimes U$ and the proof works equally

Comment: Why do you think an arbitrary subspace has that form?

Comment: Sorry about that, I realize that last comment sounded condescending, which was not the intention. I simply meant to make you realize that if $U$ was not $1$-dimensional, then there can be subspaces not of the given form.

Comment: Well an arbitrary subspace hasn't that form! This is the error that I was in my mind :) Thus  my proof is correct?

Comment: oh no problem! indeed thank you for you help!

Comment: Yes, it looks good to me, as long as you remember to mention why a subspace must have the given form in this case (you may want to prove it if it has not been mentioned previously).

Comment: uhm I'm having a problem to define the form of an arbitrary subspace :-S